# python lossless audio recording+http streaming library

Tags: python, rest, audio

I am working on a simple service to remotely record line input from an audio interface attached to a server, via REST API request.

My current solution, using [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) to manage the audio interface:

1) send HTTP request to start recording to a file on server filesystem.

2) send HTTP request to stop recording and pull the recorded audio file from the server filesystem

Instead, I would like to be able to just "stream" the line input to any http client who wants to download the audio stream.

Is there any simple python library solution to *lossless* http audio streaming directly from any audio interface's input?

More importantly, does this make sense or should I use [RTSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) instead? (More than efficiency I would like to focus on being able to download the audio stream by a simple http link on a browser or even via curl or simple programmatic request, and I'll usually not have more than one connected client at a time, that's why I'd prefer to avoid RTSP.)

Comment: flac is lossless, of course WAV is too since its just raw PCM audio with a header slapped in front ... if you control both server and client side you can stream either of these codec ... HLS which by default uses aac is not inherently a streaming codec ... aac via HLS gives impression of streaming yet its simply stitching together a series of aac clips which is what you can do here ... controlling both server and client sides gives you freedom to pick any codec

Comment: Sure but since I am streaming it would be swell not to have to include any file header like you can do, for example, with mp3 or aac

Comment: Also I need to be able to compress on the fly as the audio is captured from the interface. My current idea is to approach it by sending uncompressed raw samples and let the client build the header. The server can be queried on stram properties such as number of channels and sample rate, size and type, in order to be able to generate a proper wav header for a wav file and start stuffing it with the received samples. Still, it seems like there should already be a library for this. I don't want to do all this and find out about it later ^^'

Comment: I have the same question and I googled a lot. Wondering in this 2020 with great streaming apps in market, no one is there to answer this question properly and in detail!

Comment: @Jaydeep I never found it. I would gladly opensource my solution but it belongs to my former employer. For what is worth if I started all over today I think I would go for some FOSS HTTP broadcasting server + streaming producer solution like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icecast + https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap or something of the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this using Python flask to provide the REST endpoint to stream audio, and the pyfaac module to pack PCM frames into the AAC format (this format is needed for streaming).  Then, for example, you use the standard HTML5 audio tag with src set to your streaming endpoint.

Comment: Do you know of any lossless pyfaac equivalent?

Comment: Hm, I haven't looked, but you could increase the AAC bitrate?

Comment: No, because it is for an audio testing application :-(

Comment: I guess in that case just use a streaming response on a Flask endpoint, by writing a generator to yield PCM frames, which then get streamed to the consumer of the endpoint. As you say above, consumer then has to build the WAV or whatever. I don't think it's too much work though.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. If there is no better way that's what I'll do. Thanks!